# Pre booking doesn't work with custom bootstrap modul in woocommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using [Pre Booking](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-pre-order-for-woocommerce/) plugin on my [Website](https://www.theitaliankitchen.com.bd/shop/), Here is [example product](https://www.theitaliankitchen.com.bd/product/mozzarella/). And All product single/variable working fine in single product page. And I'd created custom templates for showing products and when click "select option" on variable Product then shows popup and show some details of that product. That's working fine. If I have any pre booking product then that pre booking option working fine on the only single product page, but didn't work on my popup, user can direct order from my popup but that product is pre booking :(, I want user can't direct order that product. so How can i show on my popup pre booking option if product is pre booking product? Please help me.  My custom template code is here.

```
<?php global $product; ?>
                        <!--Single Product by Category-->
                        <div class="single-product-by-category fix">

                            <div class="shop-single-product-img floatleft">
                                <div class="shop-product-thum">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <?php 


                                    if(has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID())){

                                         echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'com_product_img' );
                                    } else {
                                        echo '<img src="' . woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() . '" alt="Placeholder" />';
                                    }


                                    ?>



                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="shop-single-product-details floatleft">

                                <div class="shop-product-name">
                                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>                              
                                </div>
                                <!--
                                <div class="shop-product-cat">
                                    <p><?php echo $product->get_categories(); ?></p>
                                </div>
                                -->
                                <div class="shop-product-desc">
                                    <p><?php echo $product->post->post_excerpt; ?></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="shop-product-size-price">       
                                    <?php if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>                                                               
                                        <div class="shop-product-variable fix">                                     
                                            <h2><strong>Regular : </strong> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></h2>
                                        </div>  
                                    <?php else : ?>
                                        <div class="product-out-of-stock">
                                            <p>Sold Out</p>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <div class="shop-product-price">
                                        <?php echo bashar_show_variable_product_list_with_price(); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="shop-select-add-to-cart">
                                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="custom-shop-page">
                                <!-- Modal -->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                      <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_title() ) ?></h4>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="modal-body">

                                        <div class="msingle-product-image product_img_model">
                                            <!--
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID())){

                                                 echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'com_product_img' );
                                            } else {
                                                echo '<img src="' . woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() . '" alt="Placeholder" />';
                                            }
                                            ?></a>
                                            -->
                                            <?php if($product->get_gallery_attachment_ids()) { ?>
                                                <div class="owl-carousel woo-product-gallery">
                                                    <?php                                                        
                                                        $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
                                                        foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
                                                            $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
                                                            echo '<img src="' . $image_link . '" alt="Placeholder" />';
                                                        }
                                                    ?>  
                                                </div>
                                            <?php }
                                                elseif(has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID())){                                          
                                                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'com_product_img' );
                                                } else {
                                                        echo '<img src="' . woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() . '" alt="Placeholder" />';
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="mproduct-price">
                                            <h2><strong>Price : </strong> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></h2>                        
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product_variable_list">


                                        <?php wc_get_template_part('content', 'single-product'); ?>


                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Continue Shopping</button>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--/ Single Product by Category-->
```

Here is video i think you can good understating watching this video 
https://youtu.be/gbqsVHZFYzY